# \thinspace/\, inserts no space

Tags: luatex, fontspec

In my greek-german document, the second `\,` of the combination `\,--\,`
doesn't actually insert a space. It rather looks as if I wrote just `\,--`
(Often, the same occurs with other languages and fonts, but this case is the most obvious one. It probably depends just on `\,--\,`.)

[image: un-spaced thinspace]

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\listfiles
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Ligatures = {Common,TeX}]
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Ligatures=TeX]{GFS Porson}
% \usepackage{thinsp}
\begin{document}
\begin{greek}
  Οὑτωσὶ\,--\,τοίνυν, ὦ παῖ\,--\,καλέ\,--\,, ἐν\,--\,νόησον, ὡς\,--\,ὁ 
  μὲν πρότερος ἦν λόγος Φαίδρου\,--\,τοῦ Πυ\,--\,θοκλέους
\end{greek}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please try to minimize as much as you can. Kick out any font, which is not needed here. Try to find the culprit part and try to make it easier to compile for volunteers. I try to get those fonts now, but If they are not needed, it would be easier to spot the error.

Comment: Sorry, I have actually no idea when exactly the space is reduced. I remember that there were cases -- that's all. Else I had minimalized the MWE even more. So I once decided to use the next obvious example. In /this/ case, `bla\,--\,bl\,--\,ab\,--\,la` as German text works moderately fine, as it does with the Greek text when you replace `GFS Porson` with, let's say, `CMU Serif`or even `GFS Bodoni`.

Comment: You have to delete line by line. As long as you can see the error, you may continue. Just as an example, the lines `\listfiles` and all the commented out stuff would vanish. Then, with the minimum needed, you can have a look at the options of each package, which ones are really needed in order to show the issue.

Comment: The `listfile` is for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Imho it is a problem with the endash in your font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{GFS Porson}
\begin{document}
\greekfont
  Οὑτωσ \fbox{—}τοίνυν, 

  Οὑτωσ \fbox{–}τοίνυν,
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It loads `gfsporson.luc`(binary file) and `GFSPorson.otf`, but not `gfsporson.lua`. Can I redefine the `endash` and the `emdash`? In `gfsporson.lua` it say `[8211]={
   ["boundingbox"]={ 92, 210, 629, 262 },
   ["index"]=45,
   ["name"]="endash",
   ["slookups"]={
    ["ctx_tlig_2_1"]={ 45, 45 },
   },
   ["width"]=522,
  },
  [8212]={
   ["boundingbox"]={ -9, 210, 1051, 262 },
   ["index"]=51,
   ["name"]="emdash",
   ["slookups"]={
    ["ctx_tlig_2_1"]={ 45, 45, 45 },
   }`, whatever this means.