# how to set spacing after \endash or -- in Greek font (GFS Porson)?

Tags: spacing, punctuation, greek, kerning

In a [former question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257211/thinspace-inserts-no-space) I described the wrong spacing in Greek texts written in `GFS Porson` after `--` (I though it depended on `\,`, which it does not as Ulrike Fischer noted).

To sum it up: The spacing after the endash -- I always use `--` and I always enclose it in `\,` -- in `GFS Porson` is wrong. As Son of Pac-Man it eats up the following space. How do I change it best, e.g. as it is defined for `GFS Didot`?

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}[Ligatures = TeX]
\newfontfamily\othergreekfont{GFS Didot}[Ligatures = TeX]
\newfontfamily\germanfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Ligatures = {Common,TeX}]
\RenewDocumentCommand{\,}{}{\thinspace\linebreak[1]}
\begin{document}
  \foreignlanguage{german}{GFS Porson}\\
  \setmainfont{GFS Porson}[Ligatures = {Common, TeX}]
  Οὑτωσὶ\,--\,τοίνυν, ὦ παῖ\,--\,καλέ\,--\,, ἐν\,--\,νόησον, ὡς\,--\,ὁ
  μὲν πρότερος ἦν \\
  λόγος Φαίδρου\,--\,Τοῦ Πυ\,--\,Θοκλέους% , Μυρρινουσίου ἀνδρός· 
  Οὑτωσὶ \fbox{---} τοίνυν

  Οὑτωσὶ \fbox{--} τοίνυν

  \bigskip
  \foreignlanguage{german}{GFS Didot}\\
  \othergreekfont
  Οὑτωσὶ\,--\,τοίνυν, ὦ παῖ\,--\,καλέ\,--\,, ἐν\,--\,νόησον, ὡς\,--\,ὁ
  μὲν πρότερος ἦν \\
  λόγος Φαίδρου\,--\,Τοῦ Πυ\,--\,Θοκλέους

  Οὑτωσὶ \fbox{---} τοίνυν

  Οὑτωσὶ \fbox{--} τοίνυν
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At least `\linebreak1` is wrong.

Comment: Yes, no, yes, I had to look it up myself: The site doesn't show my \\ (if it doesn't appear: double backslash) after ἦν.

Comment: You shouldn't use `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`. Just select the code lines and click on the `{}` button (or hit Control-K). This indents the line by four spaces, which is the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An image clarifies well the issue

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}[Ligatures = TeX]
\newfontfamily\othergreekfont{GFS Didot}[Ligatures = TeX]

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} % just to show the problem

\fbox{--} Οὑτωσὶ--τοίνυν

\othergreekfont

\fbox{--} Οὑτωσὶ--τοίνυν

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the en-dash in Porson is shifted to the right. A bug in the font. The shift is by about 1pt, as the code

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\fbox{\kern -1pt --\kern 1pt}
```

shows

[image]

Comment: so until Porson is fixed, you could get a dash with correct spacing by defining something like `\newcommand\dash{\mbox{\kern-1pt--\kern1pt}}` or even `\newcommand\dash{\mbox{\thinspace\kern-1pt--\kern1pt\thinspace}}` if you wanted more space around it in all cases.

Comment: Not bad, but: I can't replace all of my `--`s with `\dash`es. How can I tell LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX to treat the `--` in the Greek passages and only the ones in the Greek passages in a way, e.g., as you suggest for a new `dash`? I think one can see the bug in `GFSPorson.otf`, where `U+2013` stretches -107 whatever-it-is across the right border of the inner box (and leaves a space of 92 whatever to the left). That's what `U+2013` doesn't do in `GFSDidot.otf`

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann My estimate about 1pt was right, then: the numbers are in multiples of the design size (usually 10pt) divided by 1000 (actually big points are used, but it's almost the same at this size). I guess the sidebearing on the right should be 107 and a minus sign slipped in. Maybe something can be done automatically in LuaTeX; in any case, an input such as `\,--\,` is error prone and should have been `\dash` (or whatever name you like).

Comment: Your answer confirmed my suspicion, that there <it>is</it> a buggy bug. I notified the Greek Font Society (GFS), the fathers of GFS Porson.